# Remove duplicate curly braces from string

Tags: powershell

This one is how I build the string and assign that to a variable:

```
$package = $package+$component+"=[{"+$componentField+":"+$componentValue+"}" 

Write-Host $package
```

Output:

```
efc90fde-c75c-d5e5-bd3e-7f7ce358e2e2=[{{artifacturl:http://10.1.18.12:8088/job/Xyz/640/artifact/target/xyz.war}}
```

Expecting:

```
efc90fde-c75c-d5e5-bd3e-7f7ce358e2e2=[{artifacturl:http://10.1.18.12:8088/job/Xyz/640/artifact/target/xyz.war}
```

Comment: Does any answer solve your problem?

Comment: On console it look like {{ or }}, but when I write these to a file there i found actually it is only one either { or } it means on console it shows like this only, My thing working fine with out any changes

Answer (score 0):

Just do:

```
$package = $package+$component+"=[{"+$componentField+":"+$componentValue+"}".Replace("{{", "{")..Replace("}}", "}")
```

BTW, this should also do the trick:

```
$package = $package+$component+ "=[$componentField:$componentValue"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a regex to replace the string:

```
$package -replace '({|})\1', '$1'
```

[Demo.](https://regex101.com/r/pZ4oR2/1)

However, I would suggest you to build the string using a format string:

```
$package = '{0}{1}=[{2}:{3}' -f $package, $component, $componentField, $componentValue
```